# There is a way to load roles from a specific table in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I have an app that manages all of its users inside one entity (USER), implementing the `UserInterface`, as recommended.
Linked to it, I got the CUSTOMER and the EMPLOYEE entities: each one storing specific infos about the user.

You may ask why I'm doing like this: an EMPLOYEE can be a CUSTOMER in many WORKPLACES and may work in many WORKPLACES. In order to avoid repetition, the common info got centralized in USER and the attribute `Roles` in USER is always blank in db.

The goal here is to load my roles based on specific data stored in another entity (WORKPLACE) when an EMPLOYEE logs in.

My great question may live in the `UserRepository`: when symfony calls the repository looking for the user entered on the login form, doctrine delivers it with no roles. I put my roles and return the `User` to the Authenticator (the vanilla one, I havent touched it yet). After the end of every requery, Symfony checks for the user but then doctrine loads the `ROLE_CLIENT` (in other words - no privileges).

**What I already tried** and failed

- Make another authenticator supporting the routes that need those specific rules (as seen here https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html )
- Use the `UserLoaderInterface`  *inside* `UserRepository` (as seen here https://symfony.com/doc/master/security/user_provider.html#using-a-custom-query-to-load-the-user )
- Voters (I didnt see a way to code them to my needs)

**The entities**

```
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     */
    private $cpf;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column
     * 
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column
     */
    private $nome;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column
     */
    private $telefone;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column
     */
    private $nascimento;

     /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column
     */
    private $ultimoLogin;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column
     */
    private $endereco;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column
     */
    private $cidade;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column
     */
    private $uf;

    /**
     * @var int|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column
     */
    private $cep;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="Roles", type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string")
     */
    private $password;

//vanilla getters and setters
```

*Workplace entity*

The booleans store the privileges i want to get

```
class LocalTrabalho
{
    /**
     * @var Configuracao
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Configuracao::class, inversedBy="localTrabalho")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="CNPJ", referencedColumnName="CNPJ", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * the company unique code
     */
    private $cnpj;

    /**
     * @var Funcionario
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Funcionario::class, inversedBy="localTrabalho")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="CPF_Funcionario", referencedColumnName="CPF", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * the user-employee unique code
     */
    private $cpfFuncionario;

    /**
     * @var bool
     * 
     * @ORM\Column
     * is this employee is active?
     */
    private $ativo = 1;

    /**
     * @var bool
     * 
     * @ORM\Column
     */
    private $privilegioCaixa = 0;

    /**
     * @var bool
     * 
     * @ORM\Column
     */
    private $privilegioPrestador = 1;

    /**
     * @var bool
     * 
     * @ORM\Column
     */
    private $privilegioRecepcao = 0;

    /**
     * @var bool
     * 
     * @ORM\Column
     */
    private $privilegioAdministracao = 0;
```

*Employee Entity*

```
class Funcionario
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $cpf;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column
     */
    private $ctps;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column
     */
    private $foto;
```

*An example USER tuple from db*

```
# CodPFis, email, password, Roles, Nome, Telefone, Nascimento, Ultimo_login, Endereco, Cidade, UF, CEP
'89038252099', 'sophiejenniferteresinhaoliveira__sophiejenniferteresinhaoliveira@grupomozue.com.br', '$argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=1$WEn7b64I9744kRJICEpaLA$jcYLDvh2bZsZPakMDGsncpbfIZwR6lN0QcgJOOSerK0', NULL, 'João da Silva', '', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

My last resource is asking here, after some long and wasted work hours, what should I do (or what i did wrong)?

I've seen some other threads asking similar questions, but they're outdated (im using the version 5):
[Dynamic roles in symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838188/dynamic-roles-in-symfony)
[Symfony 2 - Loading roles from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005680/symfony-2-loading-roles-from-database)
[Symfony2 - Dynamic Role Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847592/symfony2-dynamic-role-management)
[How to update roles in security token in Symfony 4 without re-logging in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59843857/how-to-update-roles-in-security-token-in-symfony-4-without-re-logging-in)
[Symfony User Logout After Role Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63556903/symfony-user-logout-after-role-change)

PS: Someone tried this approach (https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12025#issuecomment-562004005) and got success in symfony5?

Comment: The `roles` column is not a requirement of `UserInterface`, only the getter is. What I'm getting at is that you can crawl those relations and build the `Roles` array in the `getRoles` function in the entity. I can't give a more detailed explanation since you didn't tell exactly how `User` and `Funcionario` are 'linked', you could do it directly if they are modelled as relations or you might need some collaborators...

Comment: Too much detail in your question.  Perhaps you could try to reduce it to the actual problem.  I think you are saying that you are initially adding the roles and things work? But then "After the end of every requery, Symfony checks for the user but then doctrine loads the ROLE_CLIENT (in other words - no privileges)." Don't know what that means at all.

Comment: @Cerad To sum up, when a employee logs in, I intend to build its roles based on what company he "chose" to access (company's id is sent in the auth form). If that employee has no active jobs in any company (or no rules), he's granted as a client. I can get the manipulated user with the needed roles inside my `FormLoginAuthenticator`, _but for the next requests, i get no clue how to keep doing this manipulation_ because symfony asks doctrine for a fresh copy of the user from db and get no rules

Comment: @msg `User` is where I keep credentials and general info about the user. If this user works somewhere, the brazilian laws require some more attributes to be stored. The link between these entities is the _cpf_ - so in the db the `funcionario` is a "child table" of `user`. I will check out about the relations you said

Comment: That is where the user guard authenticators come in.  Check the security section in the docs.  Basically you have complete control of how the user and their roles are loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out that the best solution for my case was manipulate the `User` Repository. Doctrine uses them to operate the db so I just coded my rules inside and let the framework do the rest.

The algorithm is something like the shown below:

- Find the user using the provided `$id`
- If he/she works somewhere, load the `ROLE` constants into the `User` entity
- If he/she does not have a job, load the profile as a common user

```php
public function find($id, $lockmode=null, $lockversion = null){
        $us = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->andWhere('u.cpf = :cpf')
        ->setParameter('cpf', $id['cpf'])
        ->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();        
        $lt = $this->_em->createQuery(
            'SELECT t
            FROM App\Entity\LocalTrabalho t
            WHERE t.cpfFuncionario = :cpf'
        )
        ->setParameters(['cpf' => $us->getCpf()])
        ->getResult();

        if (count($lt) > 0){
            $regras = ['ROLE_FUNCIONARIO'];
            if ($lt[0]->getPrivilegioCaixa()) $regras[] = 'ROLE_CAIXA';
            if ($lt[0]->getPrivilegioPrestador()) $regras[] = 'ROLE_PRESTADOR';
            if ($lt[0]->getPrivilegioRecepcao()) $regras[] = 'ROLE_RECEPCAO';
            
            if ($lt[0]->getPrivilegioAdministracao())
            {
                $regras = ['ROLE_ADMIN'];
            }
            $us->setRoles($regras);
        }
        return $us;
}
```